# XSL+XPATH: Compare previous node attribute to current node attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to find out how I can compare a previous node attribute value to the current. Here's how I"m trying currently:

```
<xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[1][@title=text()[self::*[@title]]])">
```

And for reference, here's the format of just about every node:

```
<item title="myTitle" page="X" link="__WKANCHOR_1i" backLink="__WKANCHOR_1j"/>
```

Basically, I want the test to fail if a preceding node matches the title of the current node.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's what the whole XML document is formatted like:

```
<item title="myTitle" page="8" link="__WKANCHOR_w" backLink="__WKANCHOR_x">
  <item title="mySubTitle" page="8" link="__WKANCHOR_y" backLink="__WKANCHOR_z">
    <item title="mySubSubTitle" page="8" link="__WKANCHOR_10" backLink="__WKANCHOR_11"/>
  </item>
</item>
<item title="myTitle" page="8" link="__WKANCHOR_w" backLink="__WKANCHOR_x">
  <item title="mySubTitle" page="8" link="__WKANCHOR_y" backLink="__WKANCHOR_z">
    <item title="mySubSubTitle" page="8" link="__WKANCHOR_10" backLink="__WKANCHOR_11"/>
  </item>
</item>
```

All that over and over again. So, I'm at the second mySubSubTitle node and I want to make sure there isn't another mySubSubTitle node immediately preceding it. I can't use preceding-sibling since, although it's at the same nesting level, it's nested in a different set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `test="not(@title = preceding::*/@title)"` you compare the `title` attribute of the context node to any preceding one. You might however want to provide more details on the input structure and the test you need to perform, perhaps you only want to check the preceding siblings `test="not(@title = preceding-sibling::*/@title)"` or even only the immediately preceding sibling `test="not(@title = preceding-sibling::*[1]/@title)"`.

Comment: That test is exactly what I was trying, but you're right, I'm not in the right mindset using it. I'll edit with some more context.

Comment: Given the nesting and the sample you have you indeed want to use the `preceding` axis as suggested with `test="not(@title = preceding::*/@title)"`. Can you show us the XSLT where you use it and explain which output you get and which one you want, as it seems currently the suggestion is not working for you.

Comment: Right now the test passes in all cases, since I'm not able to accurately pass a true into it. I've been experimenting with `test="not(@title = preceding::*[2]/@title)"` using the 2 as different ints to try to directly compare it to the other mySubSubTitle node, but have been missing the target.

Comment: Found it. From [link](http://www.xmlplease.com/axis) I learned that preceding starts at the children and works up to parents as far as the [] number is concerned. Thanks so much.

Comment: @notkyleakers: it does not really start at "the children", actually. An XML parser usually does a depth-first traversal, the `preceding` axis does the inverse of that, starting with the last node that was visited and closed (end-tag).